# react-redux - Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-persist

I am trying to use redux persist and react-redux in my app.js file, but I am getting the following error:

> Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a , or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(App)"

Here is the code for my app.js file, where the error is occurring.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import StoreDetailsScreen from './screens/storeDetailsScreen';
import CustomerListScreen from './screens/customerListScreen';
import AddCustomerScreen from './screens/addCustomerScreen'
import AddTransactionsScreen from './screens/addTransactionScreen'
import TransactionListScreen from './screens/transactionListScreen'
import CustomerInfoScreen from './screens/CustomerInfoScreen'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {daysFromTransaction} from './redux/reducer'
import {updateFrequency} from './redux/actions'
import {store, persistor} from './redux/store';
import { createSwitchNavigator, createStackNavigator, createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import {PersistGate} from 'redux-persist/integration/react'

const TransactionsNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  AddTransactions: AddTransactionsScreen,
  CustomerInfo: CustomerInfoScreen,
  TransactionList: TransactionListScreen,
})

const CustomerNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  CustomerList: CustomerListScreen,
  AddCustomerForm: AddCustomerScreen,
  Transactions: TransactionsNavigator,
});

const MainNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  StoreDetailsForm: StoreDetailsScreen,
  Customers: CustomerNavigator,
});

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    customers: this.props.customers,
    isReady: false,
  }

  async componentWillMount() {
      await Expo.Font.loadAsync({
         'MaterialIcons': require('@expo/vector-icons/fonts/MaterialIcons.ttf')
      });
      updatedCustomers = this.state.customers.map(customer => {
        let frequency = 0
        currentDate = new Date()
        customer.transactions.forEach(transaction => {
          if (daysFromTransaction(transactionDate, currentDate) < 30)
            frequency++;
        })
        return {
          ...customer,
          frequency: frequency
        }
      })
      this.props.updateFrequency([...updatedCustomers])
      this.setState({isReady: true})
    }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isReady)
      return <Expo.AppLoading/>

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
          <MainNavigator />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  customers: state.customers
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,{updateFrequency: updateFrequency})(App)
```